# How to reduce Docky pop-up sensitivity?

Tags: unity, docky

I'm using Docky version: 2.2.1.1 Release on Ubuntu 16.04
The dock is having very high sensitivity. Whenever I bring my cursor to
the bottom of the screen, say, to open up the log cat in Android Studio,
it pop's up and covers a significant amount of my screen space
preventing me from using anything it overlaps with. I have to take the
cursor very slowly to the bottom of the screen every time I want to
access something at the bottom. Has anyone else faced this issue? Can
someone suggest an easy way to fix this, as I'm new to Ubuntu? Also, I
don't want to use other docks like Cairo because they are resource heavy
and my laptop isn't very powerful, especially when using Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Install gconf-editor from the Terminal

```
sudo apt install gconf-editor
```

Step 2: Open gconf-editor using the command

```
gconf-editor
```

Step 3: 
Navigate to the following folder:
/apps/docky-2/Docky/Interface/AutohideManager

Step 4:
Set the UnhideDelay value to 500 (note this is in ms)

Step 5:
Restart your computer 
OR 
Go to System Monitor, select the Processes tab, right click on docky and click on kill. Then restart docky like you would launch an application